# Method not found: 'Void DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase.set_HeaderIsWritten(Boolean)'

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

Faced this on my local DNN site while developing my modules. Unable to access the local site afterwards. Would appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice to resolve the problem other than reinstalling. Thanks

Error Log

> 2015-12-26 16:49:28,303 [][Thread:7][FATAL]
>   DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication -
>   System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void
>   DotNetNuke.Framework.PageBase.set_HeaderIsWritten(Boolean)'.    at
>   DotNetNuke.Web.Common.Internal.DotNetNukeHttpApplication.Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.SendResponseExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be completely wrong but that normally happens when you are referencing a DLL in your site (project) but you have another version deployed/installed that doesn't contain the method DNN is looking for. It might be worth checking the list of DLL versions listed on that stack trace.

Hope that helps.